# Combining C++/CLR and C++

Tags: c++, interop, c++-cli

I want to include third-party C++ libraries in my C++/CLI application.

What is/are the standard method(s) for doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's very little to it, C++/CLI was explicitly created to support this scenario.  Just pick a project template from the CLR node to get started.  You'll have to tell the linker to link the .lib files and #include the headers in your C++/CLI source code.

The only wrinkle you can run into is that the #include headers might contain declarations that can be misinterpreted by the C++/CLI compilers.  C function declarations for example.  Best thing to do is to the tell the compiler explicitly about it.  Like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#pragma managed(push, off)
#include "3rdparty.h"
#pragma managed(pop)
#pragma comment(lib, "3rdparty.lib")
// Rest of your code
```

The #pragma comment in that snippet tells the linker to also link the .lib file of the 3rd party library.  Saves you from having to do it explicitly in the linker's Additional Dependencies setting.

That's all.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if such standard exists, you can use C++ libraries from within C++/CLI application like you do with C++ apps.
The only thing I always try to do is to wrap 3rd library behind Proxy or Facade design pattern, so that the client would always work with managed classes.
This is especially important if your C++/CLI app is a library used by other .NET apps.

Example:

```
// 3rd party header
class Value{};

// your C++/CLI app
#include <3rdpaty/Value.h>

public ref class ValueWrapper
{
public:
    // wrapper interface here

private:
    std::scoped_ptr<Value> value_;
};
```

Comment: this won't compile as you can't use unmanaged value types as members of a managed class

Comment: You can always use forward declaration and opaque pointer to Value. This compiles and works perfectly.

Comment: This is how I did my interfacing a few months ago, and it works fine.

Comment: "*This compiles and works perfectly.*" I doubt that, given that there's no such thing as `std::scoped_ptr<>`...